# Java ERROR 1876 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter :

Tags: java, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Good day

Im experiencing the following error can someone please help me

```
`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=61449:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\dev\TrainAppUpdated\target\classes;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.26\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.8\jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.8\jackson-core-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.8\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.19\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.19\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.19.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.19\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.19.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.16.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\classmate-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-security-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.1.5.RELEASE\spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-test\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-test-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-test-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.4.0\json-path-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.3\json-smart-2.3.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\1.2\accessors-smart-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.4\asm-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\3.11.1\assertj-core-3.11.1.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\2.23.4\mockito-core-2.23.4.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.12\byte-buddy-1.9.12.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.9.12\byte-buddy-agent-1.9.12.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.6\objenesis-2.6.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\skyscreamer\jsonassert\1.5.0\jsonassert-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\google\android-json\0.0.20131108.vaadin1\android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\xmlunit\xmlunit-core\2.6.2\xmlunit-core-2.6.2.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\1.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.4\aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.2.0\HikariCP-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\5.3.10.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-5.3.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.3.10.Final\hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.23.2-GA\javassist-3.23.2-GA.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.4.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.9.4\aspectjrt-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.1.7.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.16\mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Darren\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jdbc\1.0.8.RELEASE\spring-data-jdbc-1.0.8.RELEASE.jar" ac.za.cput.TrainAppUpdated
```

.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
 \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

2019-10-01 17:14:30.906  INFO 8564 --- [           main] ac.za.cput.TrainAppUpdated               : Starting TrainAppUpdated on Darren-PC with PID 8564 (C:\dev\TrainAppUpdated\target\classes started by Darren in C:\dev\TrainAppUpdated)
2019-10-01 17:14:30.912  INFO 8564 --- [           main] ac.za.cput.TrainAppUpdated               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-01 17:14:32.865  INFO 8564 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2019-10-01 17:14:32.866  INFO 8564 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-10-01 17:14:33.115  INFO 8564 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 237ms. Found 2 repository interfaces.
2019-10-01 17:14:33.134  INFO 8564 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2019-10-01 17:14:33.134  INFO 8564 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-10-01 17:14:33.224  WARN 8564 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'accountRepository' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'accountRepository': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
2019-10-01 17:14:33.246  INFO 8564 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-01 17:14:33.251 ERROR 8564 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

The bean 'accountRepository', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

Process finished with exit code 1
`
    #spring.security.user.name=admin
    #spring.security.user.password=password

```
 #Mysql properties
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll
 spring.datasource.username=root
 spring.datasource.password=root
```

Comment: Consider renaming the bean 'accountRepository'. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.